# maven command azure-functions:run is stuck

Tags: java-8, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I am trying to run azure function on windows 10 desktop.

Running maven command "clean package azure-functions:run -f pom.xml"

As you can see in below screen shot it gets stuck while run is being executed.

[image]

In thread dump, application is stuck in main thread, stack trace is:

```
"main@1" prio=5 tid=0x1 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitForInterruptibly(ProcessImpl.java:-1)
      at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitFor(ProcessImpl.java:516)
      at com.microsoft.azure.common.function.handlers.CommandHandlerImpl.runCommand(CommandHandlerImpl.java:80)
      at com.microsoft.azure.common.function.handlers.CommandHandlerImpl.runCommandWithReturnCodeCheck(CommandHandlerImpl.java:32)
      at com.microsoft.azure.maven.function.RunMojo.checkRuntimeExistence(RunMojo.java:90)
      at com.microsoft.azure.maven.function.RunMojo.doExecute(RunMojo.java:74)
      at com.microsoft.azure.maven.AbstractAzureMojo.execute(AbstractAzureMojo.java:466)
      at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
      at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
      at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
      at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
      at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
      at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
      at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-1)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
      at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
```

In debug mode I checked variables at below location (this is also available in above stack trace)

```
com.microsoft.azure.common.function.handlers.CommandHandlerImpl.runCommandWithReturnCodeCheck(CommandHandlerImpl.java:32)
```

This is output from intellij Idea variables section for above location.

```
this = {CommandHandlerImpl@7590} 
command = "func"
showStdout = false
workingDirectory = null
validReturnCodes = {Arrays$ArrayList@7598}  size = 1
errorMessage = "Azure Functions Core Tools not found. Please go to https://aka.ms/azfunc-install to install Azure Functions Core Tools first."
```

Probably it is not able to execute func command, but I am able to execute this from intellij terminal and windows command line both. I have restarted system, intellij restarted with invalidating cache, Uninstalled and installed again azure function core tools.

```
C:\Users\sharvip>func -v
3.0.3442

java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0-internal-fastdebug"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-internal-fastdebug-_2021_05_20_01_13-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.71-b00-fastdebug, mixed mode)
```

Edit1:

I tried to debug maven using mvnDebug and I can see it gets stuck while executing Process, ProcessBuilder is created using array of Strings ["cmd.exe", "/c", "func"]. The error message is misleading, that is a String passed in function which can be returned in case of Exception. But in this case we don't application is just waiting for process (func command) to complete.